# .load() a web page into a site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I'm making a site where the different pages are brought in by `.load()`, the problem is that index.php is initially empty and my other efforts have simply loaded the page into itself or left the page empty (pages can still be emptied and loaded from #contentspace though). My current code loads nothing, i'm sure i'm doing several things wrong, I just need to know where to start. do i need to use php for this?

```
//load page into contentspace by default?
var defaultpage = "blog.php";
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#contentspace").load(defaultpage);
)};
```

Comment: Note: Try using the FireBug extension for FireFox, it'll save you plenty of time in the future.

Comment: have you checked your browser console if there was an error? Have you checked if blog.php was outputting any content at all. when you browse normally to blog.php do you see any content?

Comment: blog.php contains wordpress functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error with your closing of the $(document).ready `)};` for one. As you can see in my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/n1ck/NNpqq/9/ it is requesting the `blog.php` file.

```
//load page into contentspace by default?
var defaultpage = "blog.php";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contentspace").load(defaultpage);
});​
```

Comment: Glad I could be of some help, I would recommend using the javascript console in the browser you are developing on. It makes debugging these issues so much quicker. Firebug for Firefox, or https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console for Chrome.